# jquery colpick frozen, cant change the color

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, color-picker

Ive got a problem with jquery colorpicker which seems to be some kind of frozen, I cannot change the color in it.
here is a fiddle link which desribes it best http://jsfiddle.net/cKWNv/19/
this is how Im creating the colpicker

```
var cp = $('<div class="panel-body specular_color" id="">');
cp.colpick({
    flat: true,
    layout: 'hex',
    colorScheme: 'dark',
});
cp.appendTo(popDiv);
$('body').append(popDiv);
```